# Delete object for managing Memory heap in java

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

I try to remove object for managing memory heap.

but, it is not.. working.

I have cache data(image data).
Parent Class is Client(class name) which have a many images data.
Client(Client Class have Study Class List) >> Study(Study Class have Series Class List) >> Series(Series Class have Image Class List) >> Image(Image Class have images data).

I have tried some way(below)

1. For managing memory heap I remove the best parent class object.
   ex) client: studyList.remove(key) -> not work
2. I remove image data and all list
   ex) client: studyList.remove(key) + seriesList.remove(key) + imagedata = null -> not work;

Activity Monitor(Macbook) shows java memory heap isn't free..

Client Class have below:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Study> StudyListByKey = new HashMap<Integer, Study>();
```

Study Class have below:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Series> SeriesListByKey = new HashMap<Integer, Series>();
```

Series Class have below:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Image> ImageListByKey = new HashMap<Integer, Image>();
```

Image Class have below:

```
private ArrayList<byte[]> images = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
```

removing code Image data  is below:

```
public void removeDICOMImage() {
    this.logger.info(this.images);
    this.images = null;
}
```

not.. work.. 
How can I remove image data on memory heap??

Well.. the grand grand.. parent Class Object will be free.. Child -> free??

I'm wrong??

Comment: Freeing something in the heap does not mean the memory is given back to the OS.

Comment: The JVM does not necessarily free the memory to the operating system.  It may hold free memory in anticipation of future allocations  (it depends on JVM implementation)

Comment: Why don't you set the objects not required to null. This will ensure that GC will remove them from memory and free JVM space

Comment: then.. am i doing well?? My project need to add/remove image data(for caching) actively. so very important remove memory.. If it is not working well. Server will be died and my heart will be died.. haha

Comment: @Saurabh Jhunjhunwala because.. struggle for removing memory free :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call garbage collector by `System.gc()` or `Runtime.gc()` but it does not mean you are freeing your desired outpointing references. Its all upto JVM then OS.

Comment: firing up a GC cycle manually will in most cases be contra productive as it disturbs the strategy used by the JVM.

Comment: @Henry Thank you. now. My AWS Server sometimes dies.. by memory heap size.. how can i solve this problems. I need to remove object actively

Comment: Just make sure you don't keep references to objects around that are no longer needed and let the rest done by the JVM.

Comment: Thank you... I was confused.. because OS has a memory heap.! but JVM will manage mermory heap!